# Django serializer for one object

Tags: python, django, json

I'm trying to figure out a way to serialize some Django model object to JSON format, something like:

```
j = Job.objects.get(pk=1)
##############################################
#a way to get the JSON for that j variable???
##############################################
```

I don't want:

```
from django.core import serializers
serializers.serialize('json', Job.objects.get(pk=1),ensure_ascii=False)
```

Because it returns JSON array, not a single object representation.

Any ideas?

One way I'm thinking of: is to find a way to get a hash(attribute,value) of the object and then use simplejson to get the JSON representation of it, however I don't know how to get that hash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you serialize a model instance in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757022/how-do-you-serialize-a-model-instance-in-django)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about just massaging what you get back from serializers.serialize?  It is not that hard to trim off the square brackets from the front and back of the result.

```
job = Job.objects.get(pk=1)
array_result = serializers.serialize('json', [job], ensure_ascii=False)
just_object_result = array_result[1:-1]
```

Not a fancy answer but it will give you just the object in json notation.

Comment: Isn't the the same as putting [0] at the end of the array_result? just_object_result = array_result[0]

Comment: No.  `array_result` is an array serialized into json and will be a string bookended by `[]`'s at the start and end.  If `array_result = '[...]'` then `arrary_result[1:-1]` gives `'...'` and `array_result[0]` gives `'['`.  This question was all about serializing data into a string.  The`s[start:end]` notation is a [slice of string s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

Comment: This should be inbuilt inside a Model, like a `.to_json()` method.

Answer (score 21):

### Method-1

Use Django Serializer with ***`python`*** format

```
from django.core import serializers

j = Job.objects.get(pk=1)
response = serializers.serialize('python', [j], ensure_ascii=False)
```

---

### Method-2

use ***`json`*** format while serializing and ***loads*** the string response

```
import json
from django.core import serializers

j = Job.objects.get(pk=1)
json_str_response = serializers.serialize('json', [j], ensure_ascii=False)
response = json.loads(json_str_response)[0]
```

---

### Method-3

Use [Django REST Framework's Serializer class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)
define a serializer class and serialize the instance as

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'


j = Job.objects.get(pk=1)
response = JobSerializer(instance=j).data
```

---

**Reference**
1. [Serializer Django model object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025553/serialize-django-model-queryset-with-serializers-serialize-function)

Comment: Holy shit, thank you for Method 3. So many crazy answers out there to this and i just needed to set instance to the return object and then reference the data on it. THANK YOU.

Comment: sadly I get only the name of fields when trying to return the response from your Method 3 in an HttpResponse from view

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest using Django's `model_to_dict`. If I'm not mistaken, `serializers.serialize()` relies on it, too, but it only works for `list`, *not single model instance*. That's how you get a `dict` instance with your model fields out of a single model:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

# assuming obj is your model instance
dict_obj = model_to_dict( obj )
```

You now just need one straight `json.dumps` call:

```
import json
json.dumps(dict_obj)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Date-Time objects, apparently.

Comment: `json.dumps(dict_obj, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)` would handle datetime

Comment: sadly `model_to_dict()` doesn't handle the "use_natural_foreign_keys" option.