# Querying Django database with Jquery and Ajax

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a POST request that passes data to my database when the form is submitted.

Photo of what I mean:

[image: ][]

**home.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var postForm = $(".form-post")

            //POSTING DATA INTO DATABASE
            postForm.submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var thisForm =$(this)
                var actionEndPoint = thisForm.attr("action");
                var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
                var formData = thisForm.serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: actionEndPoint,
                    method: httpMethod,
                    data: formData,
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data)
                        $(".form-post")[0].reset();

                        //I WANT TO PASS THE NEWLY ADDED DATA TO DISPLAY WITHOUT REFRESH
                        $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '{% url "postInfo" %}',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success: function(cdata){
                            $.each(cdata, function(id,posts){
                            $('#cb').append('<li>' +posts['fields'].title+ '  ' +posts['fields'].body+ '</li>');
                        });
                    }
                    });

                    },
                    error:function(errData){

                    }

                })
            })

        })
    </script>
```

As it is now it shows multiple of the same posts every time I add a post.

This is my views

**views.py**

```
def postInfo(request): # GET REQUEST
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        mytitle = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
        response = serializers.serialize("json", mytitle)
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')



def posting(request):  # POST REQUEST
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        title = request.POST.get('postTitle')
        content = request.POST.get('postContent')
        post = Post()
        post.title = title
        post.body = content
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return HttpResponse('')
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How can I make it so it just shows the post that I have added + what's in the database without showing multiple of the same posts? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting multiples because you are asking for every post in the database to be sent upon the success of the POST request.

Assuming `cdata` is an array, you could do something like

```
let innerHtml;
cdata.forEach(function(obj) {
    innerHtml.append(`<li>${data['fields'].title} ${data['fields'].body}</li>`);
});

$('#cb').html(innerHtml);
```

`$('#cb').html(...)` will replace the HTML content of the element rather than add to it so you will not get any duplicate entries. Also using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in the `append` method can make things a little cleaner.

Or you could simply send only the post you have just created in your `posting` view in it's `HttpResponse`. This will also be faster as you reduce the number of requests made when the form is submitted.

**views.py**

```
# Other endpoints
...

def posting(request):  # POST REQUEST
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        title = request.POST.get('postTitle')
        content = request.POST.get('postContent')
        post = Post()
        post.title = title
        post.body = content
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()

        # Send new post as response
        response = serializers.serialize('json', post)
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

**home.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var postForm = $(".form-post");

    // POSTING DATA INTO DATABASE
    postForm.submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var thisForm = $(this);
      var actionEndPoint = thisForm.attr("action");
      var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
      var formData = thisForm.serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: actionEndPoint,
        method: httpMethod,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $(".form-post")[0].reset();

          // Add the new post to $('#cb')
          $('#cb')
            .append(`<li>${data['fields'].title} ${data['fields'].body}</li>`);         
        },
        error: function(errData){
          // Do something
        }
      })
    })

  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I changed to what you recommended sending the post in the HttpResponse but I am now getting TypeError: 'Post' object is not iterable. I am using - from django.core import serializers for the serialize. Same applies to @schillingt

Comment: Looking at the docs for the serializer you are using, `serialize` takes an iterator as its second argument, this is why you are seeing that error. If you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391002/django-serializer-for-one-object someone suggests that `serialize('json', [post])` should work. Remember that you will now get an array as a response.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into using Django Rest Framework to build your API https://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

Comment: Thanks finally got it to work! Using                                                          
 ` post_arr = serializers.serialize('json', [post])

    response = post_arr[1:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could have the `POST` view return the serialized instance as follows. It may not be entirely correct as I don't know what you're using for serialization, but it should give you an idea.

If you don't like that, you could inject the id's of the post as a `data-post-id` attribute in html, then only append it to `$('#cb')` if it doesn't exist.

```
def posting(request):  # POST REQUEST
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        title = request.POST.get('postTitle')
        content = request.POST.get('postContent')
        post = Post()
        post.title = title
        post.body = content
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        response = serializers.serialize("json", post)
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')

$.ajax({
    url: actionEndPoint,
    method: httpMethod,
    data: formData,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data)
        $(".form-post")[0].reset();
        $('#cb').append('<li>' +data['fields'].title+ '  ' +data['fields'].body+ '</li>');
    }
    });

    },
    error:function(errData){

    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have same problem as I stated below. I now get TypeError: 'Post' object is not iterable.