# serialize django model queryset with serializers.serialize() function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-serializer

How can I return JSON response of model queryset from a view using [django serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) ?

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http.response import JsonResponse


def some_view(request):
    qs = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', qs)
    return JsonResponse(serialized_obj, safe=False)
```

According to code snippet, the view producess a ***non-json*** response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done by using ***`python`*** format.

```
serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('python', qs)
```

Unfortunately, [Django serializer doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/) doesn't mention anything about it, but the [source code does](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/__init__.py#L26)