# How can i return single object from Django view to Jquery

Tags: django, json, django-views

If i use this

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', Book.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript') # Redirect after POST
```

Then i get json objects

but if i need to return single object

then i get error

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', singleObject)
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript') # Redirect after POST
```

The error says

```
object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs on [serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-data)

> The arguments to the serialize
>   function are the format to serialize
>   the data to (see Serialization
>   formats) and a QuerySet to serialize.
>   (Actually, the second argument can be
>   any iterator that yields Django
>   objects, but it'll almost always be a
>   QuerySet).

And then try like this:

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', [singleObject])
```

Also, [this thread answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757022/how-do-you-serialize-a-model-instance-in-django) your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **filter** instead of **get** to return single object.