# Django: how to pass request object from one view to another?

Tags: python, django, celery

Is there a way to pass `request` object from one view to another? Or do I have to dissect the request into individual parts or use `request.__dict__` and pass those?

Currenlty, because the request cannot be serialized, the below code:

```
def explorer(request):
    collect_activities_init(request)
    return render(request, 'explorer/explorer.html')

def collect_activities_init(request):
    task = collect_activities.delay(request)
    return JsonResponse({'status_url': reverse('explorer:collect_activities_status', kwargs={'task_id': task.id})})

@celery.task(bind=True)
def collect_activities(self, request):
    api = StravaApi()
    code = request.GET.get('code', '') # extract code from redirect URL query string
```

Will give:

> WSGIRequest: GET
>   '/explorer/?state=&code=3ba4hgh5ad99ea3cf8e52d8&scope='>
>   is not JSON serializable

But I need to have the request data from the first function in the last one, because its code extracts some data from the request.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: [Django pass object from view to next for processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024160/django-pass-object-from-view-to-next-for-processing)

The top answer uses sessions in order to pass the save the object and retrieve it later:

```
def first_view(request):
    my_thing = {'foo' : 'bar'}
    request.session['my_thing'] = my_thing
    return render(request, 'some_template.html')

def second_view(request):
    my_thing = request.session.get('my_thing', None)
    return render(request, 'some_other_template.html', {'my_thing' : my_thing})
```

Comment: I just tried that and got an error on the first_view:
Attribute Error: object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is not passing `request` between those functions, but rather that `celery` requires arguments passed to a celery task to be serialized.

The simple solution here would be to pull out the attributes you need from the request then pass those to the task.

So instead of

```
task = collect_activities.delay(request)
```

Do

```
code = request.GET.get('code', '')
task = collect_activities.delay(code)
```

Of course, you'll need to change the `collect_activities` task definition to accept the code as an argument, rather than a request object.